# How to fix 0x7b error on virtual PC, converted from 64bit Windows 7 with disk2vhd?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtualization

[image]

I have converted my machine using disk2vhd and tried to boot it up in Virtual PC and I got a BSOD with 0x7b error

the physicial disk is a SATA SSD and a Lenovo x201s laptop.

I actually tried with other type of converters (VMware vCenter Converter to vmdk) and hypervisors (VMWare player, Virtualbox)
all combinations and virtual disk controller setups led to the same error.
Also tried to follow guides to boot from a repair ROM and  do automatic fix,fixboot, etc. none of those helped.
I eventually found articles pointing into the direction of driver injection (tools referred were only available for 32bit), although
the repair ROM can access and list the files from the disk image.
Is this something to do with the 64 bit version?

Comment: If all the virtual hypervisors programs give you the same error then the problem is disk2vhd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Virtual PC does not support a 64-bit guest operating system.  The FAQ from Microsoft refers to Windows XP specifically, but this applies to any 64-bit OS which would be used as a guest.

Reference: See the last question on this page:  http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/faq.aspx

> Does Windows Virtual PC support 64-bit Windows XP as a guest operating
>   system?
>
> No. Windows Virtual PC and Windows XP Mode was designed to
>   help small business with application compatibility from Windows XP to
>   Windows 7. The majority of business applications currently run on
>   32-bit versions of  Windows XP.

Also see this post on TechNet:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprovirt/thread/12bdcb93-a3a1-4d85-bce7-311916e87ec7

Comment: I Agree with your conclusion.  Virtual PC does not support a x64-bit guest operating system.  The feature "XP Mode" contained within certain versions of Windows 7 certainly do not.  XP 64-bit was an odd step-child of Microsoft its support wasn't really ever great.  VirtualBox and VMWare certainly support it.  Virtual PC 2007 exists within the Windows operating system as "Virtual PC" which powers the XP Mode its not longer a "seperate" program although it is a seperate download in the form of an "update"

Comment: Thanks guys, is there any free solution out there to do P2V from a 64 bit Windows 7 host?

Comment: VMWare server is free (with registration) and VirtualBox is free, both of these should work, but you must be running a 64-bit host operating system for them to run 64-bit guest.  Also, there is a flag for virtualization extensions on your processor that has to be turned on in your BIOS to make this work (Intel-VT or AMD-V ).